# How can I invoke a method accepting Action<ISomeInterface> along with method of ISomeInterface

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, methodinfo

I am using Automapper where I am trying to invoke following method:

```
 IMappingExpression ForMember(string name, 
    Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression> memberOptions)
```

In second parameter Action contains an interface which has method

```
   void MapFrom<TSourceMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>>
         mapExpression)
```

For this method I have created local method which returns

```
expression<func<object,string>>
```

Now I am confused how can I dynamically invoke ForMember method by passing the required parameters I have.

Following is the expected result I want to achieve dynamically:

```
 map.ForMember(x.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom<string>(LocalMethod<object>(x.Value)));
```

Where map is object of Automapper's configuration and LocalMethod returns an expression is as following:

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, string>> DefaultFilter1<T>(string fieldName)
    { 
    }
```

I have done it in following way:

```
var mapMethodInfo = map.GetType()
                     .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     .Where(m => m.Name.EndsWith("ForMember"))
                     .FirstOrDefault();


                        var lamda = this.GetType().GetMethod("CreateMapFromExpression").MakeGenericMethod(baseType).Invoke(this, new object[] { x.Value });

                        var actionTypeCast = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IMemberConfigurationExpression<,,>).MakeGenericType(baseType, t, typeof(string)));
                        var action = new Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression>(proxy =>
                      {
                          var miMemberExpList = proxy.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Where(m => m.Name.EndsWith("MapFrom")).ToList();

                          var miMemberExp = miMemberExpList[11];                         
                          miMemberExp.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string)).Invoke(proxy, new object[] { lamda });

                      });

                        var result = mapMethodInfo.Invoke(map, new object[] { x.Key, action });
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Actually I am creating dynamic object with some dynamic fields for which I want to bind data from a model class. So here I am doing mapping of those dynamic fields with the key/value pair dictionary as following:

 foreach (var x in toMap)
{
          map.ForMember(x.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom("CustomFieldValues")); // 
          this is the part I need to solve
}

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html